How to Align the Position of Ones Between Two Binary Strings Using an Algorithm
If I have
string1: 1000 characters, 100 ones
0001000000010000010100000000000000100010000000000000000000000010100000001100100000000000101000010000001000100000000010000001001000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000001010001000000000000000000010000001000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000001001000000000000000000000000010001000000011000000000010000000010000000010000000001000010000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000001000000010000100000010010000000000000000000010000000000000010000000000000100000001000010100000001100000000100000010010100000000000001000110000000110001000100000000000010000000100000000000000000010000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000100000000000001000000110000000000000000001000000000000000000000000010000000000100000000010000000100010000000100000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000100010000000000000000000000111110000000100000000000011000001000000000000000000010000000000000100000001000000100000000000010010000010000000000000000001000100000000000000

string2: 1000 characters, 30 ones
0000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000101000010000000000000000000000000000100100000000000001000000000000000010000000001000000000000010000001000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The goal is to align the thirty ones in string2 with any thirty ones in string1, i.e., modify string2 with a modification key so that the 30 ones in string2 match 30 ones in string1.
The key should allow for reversing the modification of string2 to return it to its original form.
In other words I want to write three functions:
make_key(string1, string2) -> key
encode(string2, key) -> string2'
decode(string2', key) -> string2

such that string2' has 30 ones at positions which are ones in string1.
The key should consist of digits from 0 to 9 and should not exceed 20 digits in length.
I have tried rotating string2 among itself, searching for patterns, removing groups of zeros, and shuffling, but none of these methods have worked for me.
What I am really looking for is the approach of how to achieve it, then I would generate the algorithm code. It could be a mathematical solution, but there could also be some ingenious, lateral thinking solution, like finding a way to eliminate common zeros in both strings, or creating a motion snake that loops through the ones in a specific way, etc. I have tried different strategies, but without satisfactory results.
Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

What is a "modification key"? Are the specific string1 and string2 you provide an example, or is this part of the problem?

Strings are an example, but they will always be 1000 characters in size and string1 will always have 100 ones and string2 will always have 30 ones. The modification key is a key through which we can restructure string2, so that its 30 ones fit into the position of 30 ones of string1. They can be any one of string1. the goal is simply for the ones in string2 to match ones in string1. and using that key, we can reverse the modification we made in string2, so that it returns to its initial form. This password cannot exceed 20 digits and should be made up of numbers from 0 to 9.

Let's imagine that with the key 82674628276298, string2 is modified in such a way that its 30 ones coincide with 30 ones of string1. Well then we would have the objective, and then with that key, we would have to later revert the changes in string2

What is the mathematical function f that gives string2_modified=f(string2,key)?

That's exactly what I need help with. in the algorithm that makes the modification and generates the key. Then it would be doing the inverse of that algorithm with that key.

I need help in the strategy to follow, which modifies string2, generating a key of no more than 20 digits from 0 to 9. Then once I have that valid strategy with your help, I would do the reverse algorithm, in which Using the key and the modified string2, generate the original stringg2 again. But what I need help with is the strategy to follow to modify string2 in such a way that its 30 ones coincide with the 30 ones of string1 with a key no longer than 20 digits.

So you want a family of at most 10^20 automorphisms on sets of 30 numbers (from 0 to 999) such that for each set of 30 numbers and for each set of 100 numbers there's an automorphism that maps the 30 numbers to a subset of the 100 numbers. This isn't really a programming problem, it sounds more like pure maths / combinatorics, except that you probably want the automorphisms and their inverses to be easily computable.

you're right. I probably didn't know how to correctly express the origin of the solution, and it is more mathematical than programming. Although in my search for help, what I am really looking for is the approach of how to achieve it, then I would generate the algorithm code. It could be a mathematical solution, but there could also be some ingenious, lateral thinking solution, like finding a way to eliminate common zeros in both strings, or creating a motion snake that loops through the ones in a specific way, etc. I have tried different strategies, but without satisfactory results.

Hello, I took the liberty of editing your post to include the clarifications you wrote in comments. If you don't like my edit I apologise; you can rollback to the previous version of the question on the revisions page, or you can [edit] further.

The size limitation on the key seems extremely harsh; there are only 10^20 different possible keys, but for a given transformed string2' there are close to (1000 choose 30) > 10^57 candidate string2. The fact that we can choose which ones of string1 to choose might allow us to reduce this number by a few order of magnitudes if we're smart about it, but probably not enough to get it down to 10^20.

I understand. And you are right. I think the same, but I know that there is a large community of very, very intelligent people here, and maybe someone can come up with a strategy that I never thought of. I may be posing the problem mathematically, but it may be possible to solve it with a very different strategy.

You would be more likely to get an answer by asking on math.stackexchange.com. You're hoping for a "different strategy" that will solve it, but an actual mathematician will consider all obvious strategies or for example prove that the problem is impossible. (Sometimes solutions to problems in one field do come from ideas in another field, but it's uncommon and not the first thing to try). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect

This is not possible. You're effectively asking to take one of the 100 choose 30 subsets of the 1s in string1, then with at most a 20 digit number recover one of the 1000 choose 30 subsets that is string2.  But there are about 8.271755695765648e+31 possible string2s for each possible string2'. So you'd need a 32 digit key to do it.

If you had that, then this would be a questions of ranking/enumerating a given subset of a set, then using arithmetic to do the rest. And that is a computer science algorithm question.

@Stef Yes, it is the same reasoning. But we came to slightly different conclusions. Where you said probably not, I said that it was actually impossible. I didn't say "pigeonhole principle", but that is what is actually going on here.

@btilly Yup, I think you could paste your comment into an answer

I want to thank everyone for the answers and the time they have given me. Although we have not found a solution, I greatly appreciate the time spent.

@Mencey Where does the "20 digits" constraint for the key come from? Is there any way you could relax that constraint?

@Stef The size is limited by the features of the program. it cannot be larger.

@Mencey What about using 20 characters instead of 20 digits?

@Stef I appreciate your proposal. It's an ingenious proposal using lateral thinking. but the idea is to use what has the lowest "memory cost". A character would have, in theory, a higher cost, since to represent the character, we would use more than one digit, I don't know if I understand myself. I also thank you for your comment because it denotes that you have tried to find another alternative solution
